# How to perform this array filtering without using any function in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization

Let's say I have

```
$a = [1,4,5,8,9,...];
```

well containing a large range of discontinuing numbers, and

```
$p = [
  1 => [...],
  3 => [...],
  8 => [...],
  10 => [...],
  ...
];
```

containing arrays which indexes are discontinued as well.

I need to remove every number in `$a` that has a corresponding index in `$p` ...wait... without using any function.

Is it possible ? If yes, how ? If no, what is the most optimized way (wallclock-wise) to resolve that ?

Comment: With 2.253 rep you should know that in order for your question to be on-topic you need to show us what you have tried / include your research in the question.

Comment: What do you mean with "you need"? There is no real world scenario where that requirement is necessary, so either this is homework (in which case you should be solving this on your own based on what you've been learning up to this point), or this is a nonsense question. So with that said: [What have you tried?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Epodax My question leaves no room for tries, it is either you have the answer or can't even try something. But thanks for the downvote, it's great to see some people trying to moderate.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am trying to make a bigdata analyzer for a personal project. It's not that "I need", it's more like I am curious if it's possible. And no.... it's not homework sir. I realized dealing with a lot of data , functions are making things slow down (array_map, array_push, ...), I try to avoid using functions, that's all. Is really the question out of expertise ?

Comment: Are both arrays sorted?

Comment: @BusyBeaver they are not.

Comment: "without using any function" "Is it possible ?" NO.

Comment: its a logical impossibility, there is nothing to try.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you are trying to do. Tell me if I'm wrong. *Input:* `$a = [1,4,5,8,9]; $p = [4 => ['a', 'b'] , 8 => ['d', 'e']];`, *Output:* `$a =
 [1,5,9]`. Correct? If not can you add an Input/Output example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible:

```
$filtered_array = [];
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    foreach ($p as $key => $sub_array) {
        if ($key == $value) {
            // this $value of $a corresponds with an existing index in $p, so
            // do NOT add it to our $filtered_array but move on to the next
            // value of $a
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $filtered_array[$index] = $value;
}
```

Of course this will be very slow since for every entry in `$a` that is not in `$p` you will need to iterate over the entire `$p` array to find out that it isn't in there. A more efficient solution would be to leverage PHP's `OutOfBoundsException` that is thrown when you try to access an array index that doesn't exist:

```
$filtered_array = [];
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    try {
        $p[$value];
    } except (OutOfBoundsException $e) {
        // $value does not exist as an index of $p
        $filtered_array[$index] = $value;
    }
}
```

Performance might be improved somewhat if you don't need to preserve the array keys (you won't need `$index` in that case, which saves a memory assignment for every item in `$a`), but I think that difference will be negligible.

Using *some* array functions *will* be more efficient:

```
$filtered_array = [];
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($value, $p)) {
        $filtered_array[$index] = $value;
    }
}
```

Since you won't need a try/catch mechanism that passes through PHP's error handling, this will be faster.

It would probably be even faster if you allow yourself to use `unset()` to remove values that *are* in `$p`, so you don't need to create a new array but can instead modify `$a` in place. From your code example and the short array syntax, I'm assuming you use PHP 7. Since PHP 7 no longer uses the internal array pointer for `foreach`, you can safely `unset()` items while iterating. If you're running on PHP 5, you can still do that but you run the risk of `foreach` skipping over some items.

```
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $p)) {
        unset($a[$index]);
    }
}
```

Doing this will reduce the memory overhead of having a second (potentially large) array hanging around.

But since now you're already breaking your own "no functions" rule anyway, you might as well go all the way and use `array_filter` (although this does not modify the existing array but instead builds a new array, which will degrade performance for very large arrays):

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($a, function($value) use ($p) {
    return !array_key_exists($value, $p);
});
```

Comment: thanks, I saw your answer after I actually resolved my own, because I wasn't expecting too much help for that question. Actually I try to avoid functions when I have big load of data to deal with in general, that is why I made this post. We came up with similar solutions, I think tests confirm using array_key_exists is a bit faster, not so much actually. Anyways thanks

Answer (score -2):

So I answer my own question, people too busy to downvote and childishly comment saying "it's not possible", "is it homework". No it is not homework, I was just hoping some little help here (you know, as in *community*).

What I tried to achieve, remove every number in an array that has an index in another array (both having discontinued values) **without using any function** :

```
  // temporary $a
  $a_temp = [];

  foreach ($a as $avalue) {
      foreach ($p as $k => $v) {
          // if iterator $a is in the $p (we disregard)
          if ($avalue === $k) {
            continue 2;
          }
      }
      $a_temp[] = $avalue;
  }

  $a = $a_temp;
```

*(if you see a function above, please send me an email)*

---

Here some testing .

```
/********************************
 * initialize fake data
 ********************************/
$p = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $p[rand(0, 500)] = null;
}

for ($j = 0; $j < 1000; ++$j) {
    $a[rand(0, 500)] = null;
}
$a = array_keys($a);



/********************************
 * first test (without functions)
 ********************************/
$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 9999; ++$i) {

  $a_temp = [];

  foreach ($a as $avalue) {
      foreach ($p as $k => $v) {

          if ($avalue === $k) {
            continue 2;
          }
      }
      $a_temp[] = $avalue;
  }
}
$firstTestExecTime = (microtime(true) - $start);
// average time : 8s6757750511169



/********************************
 * second test, with functions
 ********************************/
$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 9999; ++$i) {

    $a_temp = [];

    foreach ($a as $avalue) {

      if (!array_key_exists($avalue, $p)) {
        $a_temp[] = $avalue;
      }
    }

}
$secondTestExecTime = (microtime(true) - $start);
// average time : 5.1003220081329


/********************************
 * printing results
 ********************************/
printf('first test execution time : %s', $firstTestExecTime);
printf('second test execution time : %s', $secondTestExecTime);
```

Sometimes using functions with a big set of data is not recommended, but in that case, it seems like `array_search` has better performance than trying to make a native code.

Comment: @rtfm sometimes you have to accept to be wrong my friend. Take a walk and ponder where you failed to understand. rickdenhaan answered my question in a very precise way without even asking details. He just understood and helped. Not like you.

Comment: Unless a NULL array key value and a non-existant array key are something you need to differentiate between I suggest you to use `isset()` instead of `array_key_exist()`. It's 2.5 times faster on average. See [here](https://ilia.ws/archives/247-Performance-Analysis-of-isset-vs-array_key_exists.html) and [here](http://maettig.com/1397246220).

Comment: @BusyBeaver wow I made a test, this is so much faster you are right. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: Happy to help, next time answer my comment... I was there to help, just wanted to understand if I got your problem right. ;)

Comment: @BusyBeaver I really appreciate that you've tried to help, thanks again. My question seems to be off-topic, but why are people so serious ? I am just here to learn things, no harm.

Comment: I think people missed where you say *"If no, what is the most optimized way (wallclock-wise) to resolve that?"*... Anyway I'm sure the question could be edited and be on-topic again just by adding your code, putting an I/O example of what you want and by admitting that functions are not bad at all even if you are trying to achieve lightspeed code. On the contrary, most of the times they are faster than your own code.